# How to make XSLT conditionally output a blank file with no DOCTYPE?

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I'm working with some XSLT transformations.  These transformations must be applied to thousands of XML documents each day in an automated way.  The resulting files should be output to a target directory.

Note that some transformations produce XML and some produce plain text.

I have a new requirement that when the input XML contains certain values, certain XSLT transformations should produce no output at all and no file should be written.

I'm processing the output from XSLT in .net, so for the XSLT that yields text, I simply check that the resulting output is either blank or only whitespace; in which case I write no file, and everything is perfect.

The problem comes when I try to recognize blank outputs from XSLT that yields XML, because even if I specify that nothing should be output in my `xsl:template` block, the output will contain an XML doctype `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` even though the document is otherwise blank.

One solution to the problem is to have my .net code filter out documents that contain only an XML doctype, but I'm not sure what the best way to do that is.  So far, I have tried and `xml.Trim().StartsWith("<?xml") && xml.Trim().EndsWith("?>")`, but I don't know how bullet-proof that is.

It would probably be better if I could somehow make my XSLT output a doctype only if there is data to be output.  I tried putting the `<xsl:output>` node inside an `<xsl:if>` node, but that doesn't work.

What's a good way to get the result I need?

Comment: What if your client outputs some specific XML that your program checks to mean that the output should be blank? This way they can modify the XSLT and get the blank output if I'm understanding

Answer (score 1):

> I have a new requirement that when the **input XML** contains certain values, certain XSLT transformations should produce no output at all and no file should be written.

What I would do is conditionally perform the transform itself. Check the XML file before the transform is run. If the input dictates that no file should be created, don't run the transform.

Comment: That would be one way to solve this problem.  I was hoping to create a solution where my client can make any needed changes on his own without bringing me back in.  Therefore, I hoped to do everything in XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **XSLT 2.0** then you can write your result documents using **[xsl:result-document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document)**, and you can decide dynamically whether to write it or not. (There will always be a primary output as well, but you can direct that to /dev/null).

Answer (score 0):

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is not a "DOCTYPE". It is an XML declaration: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd.

If you want to omit the XML declaration, use

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration = "yes"/>
```

in your stylesheet. It works in both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0. References:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-output.

Note that `<xsl:output>` is a top-level element in a stylesheet module. It cannot be put in an `<xsl:if>`, as you already noticed. See [Condition <xsl:output> in XSLT 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633984/condition-xsloutput-in-xslt-1-0) for a related discussion.

It is good practice to have an XML declaration in XML documents, but it is not compulsory. So a pure XSLT option is to always omit the XML declaration.

Comment: This looks interesting, but I mentioned in my question that I can't put `<xsl:output>` inside of `<xsl:if>`.  I need to conditionally omit the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think that mzjn's answer is probably best (always omit the declaration). But if you needed the declaration, You could use `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` in the `<xsl:output>` tag, but then just conditionally wrote the XML declaration at the top with `<xsl:text>`.