# Conditionally creating empty file /output with xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

For SAP PO I want to suppress creating xml output when one of my nodes has a certain value.

I've checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036590/how-to-make-xslt-conditionally-output-a-blank-file-with-no-doctype) but I still keep getting output in my xml (envelope / parent nodes) iow I don't get it...

My XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message"
  xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/IntertourExtTasks">
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ns1:CustAccount = '13262'">
            
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- ... output ... -->
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>            
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

SOURCE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
    <ns0:Header>
        <ns0:MessageId>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000010411998}</ns0:MessageId>
    </ns0:Header>
    <ns0:Body>
        <ns0:MessageParts>
            <ns1:IntertourExtTasks xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/IntertourExtTasks">
                <ns1:IntertourExternalTasks class="entity">
                    <ns1:BringGet>Get</ns1:BringGet>
                    <ns1:CustAccount>13262</ns1:CustAccount>
                </ns1:IntertourExternalTasks>
                <ns1:IntertourExternalTasks class="entity">
                    <ns1:BringGet>Get</ns1:BringGet>
                    <ns1:CustAccount>13262</ns1:CustAccount>
                </ns1:IntertourExternalTasks>
            </ns1:IntertourExtTasks>
        </ns0:MessageParts>
    </ns0:Body>
</ns0:Envelope>
```

Expected result when CustAccount = 13262:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Result I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
    <ns0:Header>
        <ns0:MessageId>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000010411998}</ns0:MessageId>
    </ns0:Header>
    <ns0:Body>
        <ns0:MessageParts>
            <ns1:IntertourExtTasks xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/IntertourExtTasks">
                
                
            </ns1:IntertourExtTasks>
        </ns0:MessageParts>
    </ns0:Body>
</ns0:Envelope>
```

UPDATE: Since I needed a blank output / empty file without an xml declaration I had to use omit-xml-declaration="yes". But I wasn't sure that all of my target systems could deal with xml files without a declaration so I added a conditional xsl:text at the start for 'regular output'. For completeness my xsl:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message"
      xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/IntertourExtTasks">
         <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

        <!-- If one of the nodes have a custaccount of 13262 then NO OUTPUT otherwise output XML declaration-->
        <xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/*[.//ns1:CustAccount[. = '13262']]">
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
            </xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:template>
      
        <!-- If one of the nodes have a custaccount of 13262 then NO OUTPUT-->
        <xsl:template match="/*[.//ns1:CustAccount[. = '13262']]"/>
       
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Regards, Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the identiy transformation if that is what you need in general but then block any processing for documents containing that element and value with

```
  <xsl:template match="/*[.//ns1:CustAccount[. = '13262']]"/>
```

Comment: As always you're a lifesaver Martin, thank you very much!

Comment: One more small question Martin: I want to omit the xml declaration (omit-xml-declaration="yes") . Ik know I can use sth like: 

 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;</xsl:text>

But how do I implement that to only add one line in combination with suggested solution?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to achieve as you say you want to omit the XML declaration and seem to know about `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>` but then show code to output one. Perhaps raise a new question where you explain the details.

Comment: The goal is to write an empty file when the custaccount is 13262. I've succeeded doing that thanks to you and with the omit statement the output file is empty. Most of the times however there will be output (custaccount != 13262) and in these cases I do need the xml declaration in my output.

Comment: I am not sure there is a way in pure XSLT 1, does your XSLT 1.0 processor support exsl:document? Then you might be able to conditionally set up the output with an XML declaration.

Comment: Martin, I've added the end result but I still have 2 blank lines in my output which result in a 2 byte file where I want it to be empty. Do I have whitespace / a linefeed somewhere or is this just default behaviour and related to my processor?

Comment: Looks like if I set Indent to No my line problem is solved