# XSL to suppress xml declaration conditonally (fails)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I fail to suppress the xml declaration with my following xsl. I want a completely empty xml when OWNER=0000080070:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
 
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="//IDOC/ZSCWM_TU[OWNER='0000080070']">
       </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
        </xsl:text>       
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template> 
 
  <!-- Special template  -->
  <xsl:template match="/*[//IDOC/ZSCWM_TU[OWNER='0000080070']]">
  </xsl:template>
  
    <!-- Default Template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
          
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ZSCWM_-TU_LOADLIST>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <ZSCWM_TU SEGMENT="1">
            <OWNER>0000080070</OWNER>
        </ZSCWM_TU>
    </IDOC>
</ZSCWM_-TU_LOADLIST>
```

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Required output:
BLANK XML

I must be making a stupid mistake :(

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your result - see, for example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qC98TJ. Which processor are you using?

Comment: P.S. Outputting the declaration as unescaped text is not the best practice. If you can use XSLT 2.0, then see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19038825/17153010.

Comment: Thank you Michael!
Processor: Xalan 2.7.1 in Netweaver Development Studio 7.5..24.001

javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the result in Xalan either. Neither here: http://xsltransform.net/jxDiMCa nor when run from the command line. Maybe it's a problem with your IDE.

Comment: I'm so happy and grateful for guys like you Michael. You helped me out many times, pointing me in the right direction. It was the Xalan processor. When I changed it in Eclipse to Saxon9 and figured out how to add it to the classpath in my run configuration I got it to work allright!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor such as Saxon then I would recommend

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document omit-xml-declaration=
    "{if (//IDOC/ZSCWM_TU[OWNER='0000080070']) then 'yes' else 'no'}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Nice :) Thanks Michael