# Avoiding XML declaration if test condition is not satisfied

Tags: xml, xslt, filter

I am running a transformation if a condition is not met.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- this captures the folder parameter given in the call -->  
    <xsl:param name="dir" select="dir" />

    <!-- this template iterates through the files in the input folder except for en-GB --> 
    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($dir, 'en-GB'))">
            <xsl:variable name="input-files" select="concat($dir, '?select=*.xlf')" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="collection($input-files)"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

I run the stylesheet with the following call in the command line:

```
$> java -jar saxon9.jar -it:main -xsl:this_stylesheet.xsl dir="path/to/xx-XX"
```

The condition checks whether the folder is not en-GB. If the folder is not en-GB, then the xx-XX is iterated. If the folder is en-GB, then the iteration ignores that folder and moves to the next folder in the collection.

The problem is that when that condition is met (e.g. "path/to/en-GB"), although there's no output file, there's some output on the command line, i.e. the XML declaration of the result file that will not be generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I am looking for a way to avoid this partial output, e.g. to make it also conditional on the test, so that nothing at all is output if the test is not successful.

Comment: You don't want any output to the console from that stylesheet, do you?

Comment: In general, if the stylesheet does not produce any documents using `xsl:result-document`, then, as stated in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#executing-a-transformation, "An implicit result tree is also created when the result sequence is empty, provided that no xsl:result-document instruction has been evaluated during the course of the transformation. In this situation the implicit result tree will consist of a document node with no children.". It might be best to change the main output method to `text` and use a different one for your `xsl:result-document` instructions.

Comment: No, no output wanted to the console. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use e.g. `<xsl:output method="text"/>` for the primary transformation result and add  `<xsl:output name="docs" method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />` for your documents and then use e.g. `<xsl:result-document format="docs" ...></xsl:result-document>` in the part of the code you have not shown.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>`, and then conditionally add the declaration back in as text.

See this other post for a code sample:

- [Condition <xsl:output> in XSLT 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633984/condition-xsloutput-in-xslt-1-0/43105766#43105766)

Comment: I haven't tried, but assuming it works in XSLT 2.0 too, this appraoch sounds good too.